# Creating VBA charts

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I am in the middle of a problem: I need to use the combobox value as I key to search a data in other plan and when I find the same value, capture some some cells values in the same row and plot this. Could someone help me? I believe that my great problem is create some loop with charts, because I need to verify if this value is greater than 0.01 to capture it.
Attempts so far:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()

x = 751
y = 1

If Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 7).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value Then

Sheets("Análises").ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
ChartObjects("Chart 3").SeriesCollection.NewSeries
ChartObjects("Chart 3").SeriesCollection(1).Name = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 7).Value

If Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 7 + y).Value > 0.01 Then

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=Data!$L$752,Data!$N$752,Data!$R$752,Data!$T$752"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Data!$H$10"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=Data!$H$10,Data!$J$10,Data!$L$10,Data!$N$10"

End If

Else

x = x + 1

End If

End Sub
```

I know this dont make much sense. I performed a macro to see how works with charts, but I realized this way I am trying to do, wont work. Somehow I need to pick up as value for my chart some cells (they are not sequencial) which will depend from ComboBox1 choose.

I already found how I capture the range with a loop, just need to put in chart now:

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim rng As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

y = 8

For x = 751 To 1000 Step 1

If Me.ComboBox1.Value = Worksheets("Data").Cells(x, y - 1).Text Then

 Set rng = Worksheets("Data").Cells(x, y)

    Do Until y > 36

    y = y + 2

    Set rng = Application.Union(rng, Worksheets("Data").Cells(x, y))

    Loop

   rng.Copy

 End If

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: *What have you tried so far*?  Please see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and revise your Q with appropriate details and specific problem(s).

Comment: I am so sorry sir, I havent read this section, but here will go attemptings so far:

Comment: You will need to *edit* your original question to include the code. Code does not fit or display properly in the comments.

Comment: That's the code above

Answer (score 0):

> I believe that my great problem is create some loop with charts

Use appropriate object variables:

```
Dim cObj as ChartObject
Dim cht as Chart
```

Then loop using `For/Next`:

```
For each cObj in ...
    Set cht = cObj.Chart '## Chart is child of ChartObject
Next
```

Like this, maybe (I am not sure *where* you need to loop or what other logic you may require):

```
Dim cObj As ChartObject
Dim cht As Chart
Dim srs As Series
Dim x as Long
Dim y as Long

x = 751
y = 1

If Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 7).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value Then

For each cht in Sheets("Análises").ChartObjects
    Set srs = cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    srs.Name = Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 7).Value

    If Sheets("Data").Cells(x, 7 + y).Value > 0.01 Then

    '## NOTE: I suspect these ranges also need to change for each chart
    '         That is going to be better suited for a SEPARATE question.

    srs.Values = "=Data!$L$752,Data!$N$752,Data!$R$752,Data!$T$752"
    srs.XValues = "=Data!$H$10"
    srs.XValues = "=Data!$H$10,Data!$J$10,Data!$L$10,Data!$N$10"

    End If
Next

Else

x = x + 1

End If
```